# How to write 'Junits for a Vertx microservice which is interacting with Oracle DB'?

Tags: java, vert.x, openjdk-11

I need to write the junits for a oracle-wrapper (basically a microservice written on vertx which is interacting with oracle db).How to proceed?Mockito can't be used

Answer (score 0):

How about using an in memory database eg: **h2 database**. Which can run in oracle compatibility mode:

> To use the Oracle mode, use the database URL
>   `jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=Oracle` or the SQL statement `SET MODE Oracle`.

Answer (score 0):

First you write unit tests focusing on establishing that the Dao is working properly, that is every insert, delete, update and query is working as intended and so on. This approach would assume that the network access is working properly to the microservice from the clients.

Example:

```
public class MyFirstdao {

     private static final MyFirstDao dao = new MyFirstDao(dbAddress, dbName, ...);

     @Test
     private void insert() {
          SomeResult result = dao.insert(InsertSomeObject);
          assertSomething(result);
     }

    ...
}
```

After that you can create a fake client that you can use to access the microservice and perform predefined operations. Though if you only have one type of client accessing your microservice I would probably put these tests on the client rather than having to write the same code twice. I'm just speculating here but I hope it was of use.